# Is the field of complex numbers the field of rational functions over a subfield?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

My question is the same as the title. In fact, it is another question which leads me to think about this question: For which positive integer $n$ for which there is a subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $[\mathbb{C}:K]=n$. I tend to believe this is true for every $n$, and it is indeed the case if my first question is affirmative. Thank you.

Comment: It is a theorem from 1927 due to Artin and Schreier that if an algebraic closure has finite degree, then that degree is $2$, and it's a splitting field of $x^2+1$.

Comment: Commenting on the title question. If $K$ is any field then the field of rational functions, $K(x)$ for some $x$ transcendental over $K$, cannot be algebraically closed. After all, $\sqrt x\notin K(x)$, but $\sqrt x$ is clearly algebraic over $K(x)$. Of course, the answer to the title question also follows from a theorem of Artin & Schreier that Arthur described.